# Is there a problem with filtering questions after selecting them for the site homepage?

Tags: discussion, filtering, homepage

I occasionally open an incognito window on my [favourite Stack](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) just to check if there are any interesting questions on tags I have ignored.

Today a large number of negatively-scored posts have been edited, and when I visited the homepage I saw only 3 posts, instead of the expected 15 (see image below).  Checking against the most recently active questions page, these 3 are the only non-negatively rated questions in the most recently active 15 questions.

Does it make sense to filter out the negative questions *after* picking the set of 15?  It seems counter-intuitive to me, and I would instead expect to see the most recently active 15 questions that are not negative.

(It also doesn't look great to show a potential new user just 3 questions; the site looks a bit abandoned.)

[image: SciFi homepage showing only 3 posts]

Comment: I can't repro this.

Comment: Voting to close this older question because the other one has a status tag.